How to install intl and imagick library for PHP8.3 on Ubuntu 22.04
I have PHP8.3 installed on Ubuntu 22.04. However, when I install WordPress, it suggests two PHP modules have to be enabled, intl and imagick.
I search the apt repository, and notice that both libraries are only available on PHP 8.1 or low, which can be installed via:
sudo apt install php8.2-intl php8.2-imagick

But there is no php8.3-intl or php8.3-imagick. What should I do to install these 2 PHP modules?

E: Unable to locate package php8.3-imagick


E: Unable to locate package php8.3-intl


Ubuntu 22.04 shipped with PHP8.1. As such, if you have 8.3 installed, you will need to check with the source repositories you used for 8.3 to see if these packages are available.

First you have to add the ppa:ondrej/php repository, because php8.3 packages are not in the official Ubuntu 22.04 repos.
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

Install the packages:
sudo apt install php8.3-intl
sudo apt install php8.3-imagick


I already have this PPA, but still php8.3-intl and php8.3-imagick cannot be found. Yet I found the reason afterwards, since I had upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04, the PPA still marks the distribution as "focal" instead of "jammy", therefore the previous apt install cannot find the 2 packages.

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php8.3-intl
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.3-intl'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php8.3-intl'```
